# Can someone explain how programs are allowed to re-check themselves to run at startup despite the fact I have previously unchecked them?

Tags: windows-7, boot, msconfig

I am talking about the menu in msconfig (system configuration) for windows operating systems. On the *Startup* tab I will uncheck things I don't want to run on startup such as Adobe reader, or Itunes, or Google Music and if I restart my computer they run at startup anyways and are magically checked again when I look at the menu.

What am I not understanding about this menu? My first thought was that only slimy programs or malware would do this, but even major players like google, apple, and adobe are doing it? Is it intentional?

Comment: If you delete the entry from the register that handles this behavior this its not possible for them to start-up.  So that tells me you are just disabling them for the single reboot which is what typically most people actually want.

Comment: msconfig can be a little titchy some times. try sysinternals autoruns instead.

Comment: So this menu isn't for permanently stopping things from running on startup? Just for one reboot cycle? I did not know that.

Comment: No, it's not just one reboot: the problem is that many programs insert this setting each time they are called. This means that if you don't run a program during a boot cycle the start-up setting will remain disabled. Unless a program allows you to disable "Start with Windows" as an internal setting, you are stuck with this behaviour, frustrating as it is. The only work-round might be to clear these settings as part of a shut-down procedure, but even then it may fail if one of these programs is active at shut-down and re-inserts its start-up setting when it receives the terminate signal.

Comment: That is frustrating. Is the root cause of this poor OS design? You'd think there'd be a way to prevent this from happening permanently to prevent this kind of lame behavior.

Comment: I would say it's poor application design (and it's not normal for me to defend Windows). There is an OS requirement for start on boot-up, and once there it's open to abuse. You may be able to stop the applications from making entries by manipulating permissions, but there are several places where start-up entries can be made, so you have to cover all of them.

Comment: Sometimes they install a service which is set to start at boot that does this too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable autorun from the application itself, or delete entries from this registry path: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run**